# Difference between returning a const reference and rvalue reference

Tags: c++, c++11, rvalue-reference

If I'm not wrong, I think that both a const reference and a rvalue reference can bind to a rvalue. Is there any practical difference between a function that returns the former and a function that returns the latter?

EDIT. I cannot modify the former, but why would I be interested in modifying a rvalue? Does it make sense?

Comment: Right, I was guessing so. I'll edit the post...

Comment: If you are talking about **returning** then you probably don't want to return an *rvalue-references*. While there might be some use case that could be implemented by returning an *rvalue-reference*, in most situations it will cause undefined behavior.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

A `const` lvalue reference can bind to anything. An rvalue reference can only bind to non-`const` rvalues.

```
            non-const lvalue   const lvalue   non-const rvalue   const rvalue
const T&    yes                yes            yes                yes
T&&         no                 no             yes                no
```

As you can see, they are very different.

In addition, if a function call returns an lvalue reference, that expression is an lvalue, but if a function call returns an rvalue reference to object, that expression is an xvalue.

> A function call is an lvalue if the result type is an lvalue reference type or an rvalue reference to function type, an xvalue if the result type is an rvalue reference to object type, and a prvalue otherwise.

As for when you would want to modify an rvalue - well this is precisely what move semantics are all about. Consider the following function call:

```
void func(std::string);

func(std::string("Hello"));
```

The expression `std::string("Hello")` is an rvalue that creates a temporary object. When initializing the `std::string` parameter with this rvalue, it will choose the constructor that takes an rvalue reference - the *move constructor*. This constructor then steals things from the rvalue, which is typically much faster than doing a full copy. We can steal from it because we *know* it's temporary.

As for when you should return `const` lvalue references or rvalue references:

- Returning a `const` lvalue reference is most commonly used when you want to give access to read an "internal" object (perhaps a member of a class), but not allow people to modify it.
- Returning an rvalue reference is most commonly used (not common at all) when you want to allow calling code to move from an "internal" object (perhaps a member of a class). So instead of moving from a temporary returned object (as they would when returning by value), they literally move from the internal object.

  This could also be achieved with a non-`const` lvalue reference, but then they would have to explicitly `std::move` it.

So it's not very likely that you'll need to return an rvalue reference.

Not that [`std::forward`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/forward) has a return type that looks like `T&&`. However, this is deceptive, because it may or may not be an rvalue reference depending on the type of `T`. See [universal references](http://isocpp.org/blog/2012/11/universal-references-in-c11-scott-meyers).

Comment: Side note: I'd say it's quite rare for a program to produce `const` rvalues.

Comment: Thanks. But is there any practical case where I need to return a rvalue reference?

Comment: OK, if I understand well, returning a rvalue reference makes sense when I'm passing this returned reference to another function that is intended to "steal" the object.

Comment: @jbgs No, there are not many good reasons to return an rvalue reference. I'll add it to my post.

Comment: So if I return a const reference, what happens if I pass it as parameter to a constructor? I guess the move constructor wouldn't be chosen.

Comment: @jbgs No, the copy constructor would be chosen. Typically, you should prefer to pass by value.

Comment: OK, I think I understand the meaning of returning a rvalue reference. Besides some uncommon cases, it seems it doesn't make sense to return one. Thanks

Comment: I'm not sure I follow the logic in your first bullet point.  Returning by value (instead of const lvalue reference) would require copy-constructing the return value even if the caller only wants to read from it.  Why is that preferable?

Comment: @AndrewDurward You make a good point. Thanks! I'll correct it. I crossed two of my thoughts over. It's better to return by value if the object you're returning isn't going to exist any longer. Then the return can be a move. But yes, I was talking about returning "internal" objects, which is a different case.

Comment: Is this right? rvalue reference cannot take lvalue? If that is true, how perfect forwarding works? https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd293668.aspx

Answer (score 4):

> Is there any practical difference between a function that returns the former and a function that returns the latter?

The question seems to be ill-formed. A function that returns a constant *lvalue-reference* provides access to an object only for *reading*, while a function that returns an *rvalue-reference* provides access for *moving* which means that the caller can take the contents of the referred object and *move* it to a different object. They are not comparable by any means.

In both cases, the references must point to an object whose lifetime spans beyond the end of the function that is returning it, as otherwise the caller will trip with undefined behavior on using that reference.