# An rvalue reference can only bind to non-const rvalues?

Tags: c++, c++11, rvalue-reference, rvalue, pass-by-rvalue-reference

Previous post indicated a rvalue reference can only bind to non-const rvalues:
[Difference between returning a const reference and rvalue reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15681691/difference-between-returning-a-const-reference-and-rvalue-reference#comment22263043_15681727)

However, if that's true, how [perfect forwarding](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd293668.aspx) works?

For this definition for [perfect forwarding](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd293668.aspx):

```
template <typename T, typename A1, typename A2>  
T* factory(A1&& a1, A2&& a2)  
{  
   return new T(std::forward<A1>(a1), std::forward<A2>(a2));  
}
```

It seems the factory function could take any types of data: const lvalue, lvalue, rvalue.

(P.S. seems rvalue reference could do everything, but I rarely see code write by other using it, why not? It seems rvalue reference for a function argument could not only do the things a lvalue reference could do but also improves efficiency by avoiding unnecessary copies)

Comment: https://isocpp.org/blog/2012/11/universal-references-in-c11-scott-meyers

Comment: Your arguments `A1` and `A2` are **not** rvalue references! Instead, they are *forwarding references*. These are something *entirely* different which just happens to use a similar looking syntax.